# ord and complex in haskell

Tags: haskell, complex-numbers

I have this function:

```
function x y z w = x >= y && z == w
```

For defining the type I thought about this:

```
function:: Ord a=> a-> a->a->a-> Bool
```

The problem is that I'm not taking into account the complex numbers. How I can define it including them?

Comment: Why not `function :: (Ord a, Eq b) -> a -> a -> b -> b -> Bool`?

Comment: How to define an ordering among complex numbers? Technically, any set can be made well-ordered, in fact this seldom makes sense. You may order it lexicographically, first compare real parts and, when equal, imaginary ones; or use polar form and compare radii first, then arguments.

Comment: This question is basically unanswerable. You've said "this function doesn't do what I want", but you haven't gone on to the "and what I want is..." part.

Comment: @DanielWagner what I want is that the function that I write accept also complex numbers, but in the way I'm defining it, it can't do that.

Comment: You need to define an implementation of ```Ord``` for ```Complex```

Comment: @Rainbacon I'm asking which is the type that would include ordenable numbers and also complex numbers. So I have to do a special implementation? Doesn't exist allready one

Comment: @cde33 Accept complex numbers and do what with them, exactly? You need to explain what this function is going to be used for, or else my answer is going to be `function _ _ _ _ = True`.

Comment: There is no standard definition of an ordering for complex numbers since in mathematics they are not ordered (no satisfactory ordering can be defined). You did not specify _how_ the complex should be ordered, not why do you need such ordering.

Comment: @cde33 Is 2+3i greater than 3+2i?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer is that you cannot, or should not.

`Ord` is the axiom of [trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_%28mathematics%29), which complex numbers apparently do not satisfy. So I don't think there's a total implementation for `compare` possible (though I might be misunderstanding):

```
Prelude> :info Ord
class Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
  ...
Prelude> :info Ordering
data Ordering = LT | EQ | GT    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
```

This explains why no one has defined an `Ord` instance for you already.

See:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/257208
- http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/complex_compare.shtml

Comment: Your second link directly contradicts you, exhibiting a total order on complex numbers in the first paragraph.

Comment: @DanielWagner ah shoot, I carelessly skimmed that link and thought they want on to imply contradiction on that ordering.